# Textbox enabling

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

**How to set certain textbox mandatory when a radio button is clicked in mvc?**

```
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="~/Main/Screen" method="post">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">TEST ORDER FOR PATIENT</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <h3><label class="control-label">PATIENT CODE<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="InputPatientCode" name="InputPatientCode" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

                    <h3><label class="control-label">VISIT NO<span class="inp">*</span></label></h3><input type="text" id="VisitNo" name="VisitNo" value="" style="height:30px;" /><br />

                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add" type="submit" onclick="return IsValid()";>ADD</button>
<input type="radio"/>enable
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Tried any code?

Comment: where is the radio button

Comment: <input type="radio"/>enable

Comment: I think `<input type="radio"/>` is radio button which OP want to mention with. But without an `id` attribute it's hard to find which radio button will enable text box "required" validation.

Comment: i will add a id for radio button. What is the code or procedure to do mandatory textbox on clicking radio button?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

1. Have ids for your text boxes and radio buttons.
2. Add an onClick javascript function for the radio button that you are concerned about.
3. Within that javascript function, look up for the text box that you are interested in, and set it's required attribute (`<input type="text" id="someId" required />`)